# Can an endpoint behavior accept parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am using message inspector in WCF application to store request & responses, into DB.

Whether to store these data in DB or not has to be restricted based on userInput received in the front-end.

To cut the long story short, I need help to address these issues -

1. States in page context are not available in the extensibility points
   interface.
2. Inspectors method also do not accept any custom
   parameters.

In this case, How can we pass the parameters to the WCF extensibility points for customizations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) interface receives a IClientChannel on each call, which is in turn an IExtensible. You would have to implement an custom [IExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586703.aspx), and extend the client channel when it's initialized (using an [IChannelInitializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ichannelinitializer.aspx) implementation). You could then retrieve the extension from the channel parameter in the inspector method implementation, and use it as a means of communication with you front end..